# GWT 2.4.0 with Google Web Toolkit Plugin 3.8.0.v201410302155-rev-r42

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I  have a customer requirement of GWT 2.4.0 due to a Java 5 limitation. Up until this latest Google Web Toolkit Plugin update I have been able to successfully use the plugin with GWT 2.4.0. I am seeing an error regarding a missing gwt-codeserver.jar and the GWT plugin says that GWT is not installed. Is there anything I can do as a workaround for using GWT 2.4.0 and the latest Eclipse/GWT plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I have downloaded the newest version of GWT just to copy the gwt-codeserver.jar in my SDK folder. So I didn't have the error anymore.
Also, in my debug/run configuration, I have removed the argument "-nosuperDevMode".

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem and like Gildas, I copied the gwt-codeserver.jar from GWT 2.6.0 into the 2.4.0 folder.

The next thing I had to do to get it to work was, when adding the 2.4 SDK, I had to point to the gwt2.4.0 folder as opposed to the parent "com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080121-rel-r42" folder.  Clean and build, good to go...with this problem, at least.